# Android Fragment with it's own toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-support-design

I need to create an app with normal toolbar and collapsing. Both implementations should be in the one activity. How is it possible to replace `Activity's` content fragment with the fragment that has `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and later replace it with fragment which has a normal toolbar.

Comment: Did you know, you can add code here too?

Comment: @devaldcool, I have no code, I'm just interesting how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)` in your fragment to inflate a different menu or you can use `getActivity().getActionBar()` and perform operations on the action bar directly based on your needs.

Comment: So I get normal actionbar, how can I change it to the CollapsingToolbar?